# Genus of a finite simple undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite simple undirected graph and it has subgraph $G_1,\dots,G_n$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $E(G_i)\cap E(G_j)=\emptyset$, for $i\neq j$, where $E(G)$ is the set of all the edges of $G$. Also $G_i \cong K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$. Then is it true that the genus of $G$ is greater or equal to the sum of genera of each $G_i$, that is $\gamma(G) \geq \underset{i=1}{\overset{n} \sum } \gamma(G_i)$  ($\gamma(G)$ denote the genus of $G$)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [that's true, and proved in 1962.](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1962-68-06/S0002-9904-1962-10847-7/S0002-9904-1962-10847-7.pdf)

Comment: $G_i$, may not be blocks or components. And $|V(G_i) \cap V(G_j)|$ may be greater than or equal to 2. Does the result still hold in such a case?

Comment: Actually, I could't see, how to use the paper you have cited to prove my conjecture.

Comment: The general case, where multiple vertices are identified is not at all obviously true, since some very similar statements are false.

Comment: Could you give me some more hint, how to show that it is true? Thank you. Because in the above questions,  $|V(G_i)\cap V(G_j)|$ may be greater than or equal to 2.